# Access SSIS Projects Stored in MSDB Database in BIDS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a database server (db1) that has SSIS installed and configured (SQL 2008). I have configured it so I can remotely connect to SSIS through SSMS. Now I am trying to open one of these SSIS projects that is in the MSDB database? I know in SSRS it is easy to deploy to the server reports, but I'm not seeing a way to open or deploy SSIS projects?
Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects themselves are not stored in MSDB, only the compiled packages.  You have to have an existing SSIS / BI project in your file system / source control / etc in order to open/edit or deploy.

If you don't have the original project you can import an existing package into a new project.

1. Create a new Integration Services project
2. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on SSIS Packages and choose Add Existing Package
3. Fill in the server, path, etc information on where your package is in your SQL instance

It'll then added to your project and you can edit away.

To deploy to MSDB you go to the File menu and choose Save Copy of Package as and then fill in your target info for the server.